# Self-updating graphs - how to start?

Tags: java, graphics, graph

I'd like to plot graphs with java. It should read the data from file, and update a graph - let's say value over time. While reading, it should self update and self-scale according to the value (higher or lower).

How could I best start? Which API or tool is best for java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which API or tool is the best is subjective. One API that I have used and would recommend is [LiveGraph](http://www.live-graph.org/). Its pretty flexible and covers the functionality you mentioned that you need.